# How do you connect to multiple databases on a single webpage?

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering  how i can connect to multiple databases on a single PHP webpage.
i know how to connecet to a single database  using:

```
enter code here:
               $dbh=mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password)or die("unable to connect to MYSQL");
```

However,can i just use multiple "mysql_connect"commands to open the other databases,and how would PHP know what databases i want the informaion pulled from if I do have multiple databases connected

Comment: And as always the hint: the old and outdated mysql connector has been deprecated quite a while now. It is not part of php7 any more. One should not use it any more, one should not implement new code based on it. That all is _clearly_ documented. Move to `mysqli` or `PDO`. You will also gain more safety if you do that right.

Comment: Stop using the **deprecated and as of PHP7 removed** `mysql_*` functions. Migrate to PDO and start using Prepared Statements.

Comment: There is a dupe target for your `mysql_`. But time to get onto the `mysqli` or `PDO` bandwagon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple variables to point at different database connections. Just call the connect and assign the handle to another variable.